# Is it possible to set a 3 computers LAN using just cables?

Tags: lan, utp

I'm absurdly new on networking, and I just want to know if it possible to set a network with 3 computers without a router, switch; just UTP CAT5 cables (or any category)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's theoretically possible *if* one of the computers has two network interfaces. Otherwise, how would you connect them all? But that would be a kludge at best.

If you are actually thinking about doing this, don't bother.  Network switches are very cheap.

Comment: The poster explicitly asked "without a router" and "with cables", telling him that it will work with a[n additional NIC] doesn't answer the question. – Teun Vink♦

Comment: "using two NICs" doesn't answer the question "can I use only cables?" The fact that (you assume) [OP has 2 NICs] is used more is totally irrelevant in this context.– Teun Vink♦

Comment: Ridiculous commens, No?

Comment: Why are you impersonating @TeunVink ?  Can't you stand behind your own opinions?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could get old school and use 10Base2 if you  find the proper networking cards for your computers. You just need some RG58 cables, some T connectors and two terminators.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are talking about Ethernet:

> Ethernet was originally based on the idea of computers communicating
>   over a shared coaxial cable acting as a broadcast transmission medium.

...

> In a modern Ethernet, the stations do not all share one channel
>   through a shared cable or a simple repeater hub; instead, each station
>   communicates with a switch, which in turn forwards that traffic to the
>   destination station.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet#Shared_media)

Practically speaking, you don't need any cables at all.  WiFi (wireless LAN) technology is dirt cheap and has reached LAN speed/performance.  Every laptop, tablet, and smartphone ships with a WiFi network interface card, NIC.  Many PC's ship with them, or can have one plugged in.

All you need is a WiFi access point, sometimes called a WiFi router.

Comment: The poster explicitly asked "without a router" and "with cables", telling him that it will work with a wifi router doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TeunVink My answer addressed the "with cables" part (and assumption of Ethernet) and finishes by addressing the "absurdly new on networking" part.  Nobody uses wires/cables for their (personal) network connectivity anymore.

Comment: "You can use wifi" doesn't answer the question "can I use only cables?" The fact that (you assume) wifi is used more is totally irrelevant in this context. Your quote about ethernet doesn't answer doesn't clarify if it's possible to build a network without routers or switches either. The poster isn't asking for the best way to solve this, he's asking if something is possible. If that's the best or normal way to do so is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @TeunVink "In a modern Ethernet, the stations do not all share one channel through a shared cable" is included in my answer.  Is that not directly addressing the question?

Comment: Your Wikipedia quote only tells what's common practice, not if what the OP asked is possible at all.